# Looping over a list of queries for API calls in R

Tags: r, api, loops, for-loop, bing-api

**Background:**
I wish to extract news articles via Bing News Search API based on a list of queries. The API documentation provided https://rapidapi.com/microsoft-azure-org-microsoft-cognitive-services/api/bing-news-search1/ works fine, as shown in the following:

```
library(httr)
url <- "https://bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com/news/search"
queryString1 <- list(
    q = "query1",
    safeSearch = "Off",
    textFormat = "Raw",
    freshness = "Month"
    )
response1 <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(
    'x-bingapis-sdk' = "true", 
    'x-rapidapi-host' = "bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key' = "APIkey"), 
    query = queryString1, 
    content_type("application/octet-stream")
    )
df1 <- content(response1, "text")
```

I would use the same script for subsequent queries by copying and pasting while manually changing the query (denoted as query1, query2, query3 and so forth). Then using fromJson and rbind, I convert the results of these different queries to a large consolidated data frame, which is my ultimate goal.

**Problem:** For a few queries, this task would be simple. However, it becomes tedious when my list of queries expands.

**Question:** So I was wondering if I can solve the problem by looping through my list of queries, instead of having to use the API documentation script and change the query each time? Or is there any other method to solve this problem? I struggle to understand how to write loops for API calls in R and I have attempted without success, as shown below:

```
querylist <- c("query1","query2", "query3") #using 3 queries as an example
querydata <- data.frame(querylist)
url <- "https://bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com/news/search"

for (i in 1:nrow(querydata)) {
    queryString[i] <- list(
        q = "[i]",
        safeSearch = "Off",
        textFormat = "Raw",
        freshness = "Month"
        )
    response[i] <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(
            'x-bingapis-sdk' = "true", 
            'x-rapidapi-host' = "bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com",
            'x-rapidapi-key' = "APIKey"), 
            query = queryString[i], 
            content_type("application/octet-stream"
            )
        )
    df[i] <- content(response[i], "text")
```

The output/error that I had is shown below:

```
Error in content(response[i], "text") : is.response(x) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In queryString[i] <- list(q = "[i]", safeSearch = "Off", textFormat = "Raw",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In response[i] <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(`x-bingapis-sdk` = "true",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be better to use something like `lapply` to keep all your objects in a list. This makes things much easier to work with in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the different query outputs in a list. For that, you have to initialize the list outside the for loop. And I think, you don't want to name every query "[i]", but paste the content of i to "query". I changed that in the code below:

```
querylist <- c("query1","query2", "query3") #using 3 queries as an example
querydata <- data.frame(querylist)
url <- "https://bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com/news/search"

queryString <- list()
response <- list()
df <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(querydata)) {
  queryString[[i]] <- list(
    q = paste("query",i,sep=""),
    safeSearch = "Off",
    textFormat = "Raw",
    freshness = "Month"
  )
  response[[i]] <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(
    'x-bingapis-sdk' = "true", 
    'x-rapidapi-host' = "bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key' = "APIKey"), 
    query = queryString[[i]], 
    content_type("application/octet-stream"
    )
  )
  df[[i]] <- content(response[[i]], "text")
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much!
FYI, as my queries are not sequential, I have changed this specific line of code as shown:
`q = paste("query",i,sep="")` to `q = paste(querydata$querylist[i],sep="")`

Comment: Great! You don't need the paste-function for that, `querydata$querylist[i]` will be enough. You can also accept my answer somewhere, when it answered your question sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SaskiaSchirmer help, I have managed to solve this problem and got the results I wanted without error. As my queries are not sequential, I have only changed this specific line of code in Saskia's script as shown:
`q = paste("query",i,sep="")` to `q = (querydata$querylist[i]`

Cheers!